# Dojo parser changes button id

Tags: dojo

I have the following code, straight from the tutorial:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
    <script src="js/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: 1, parseOnLoad: 1"></script>
    <script>
      require(["dojo/_base/fx", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/parser", "dojo/domReady!"], function(fx, on, dom, parser) 
      {
        var fadeOutButton = dom.byId("fadeOutButton"),
            fadeInButton = dom.byId("fadeInButton"),
            fadeTarget = dom.byId("fadeTarget");

        on(fadeOutButton, "click", function(evt)
        {
          fx.fadeOut({ node: fadeTarget }).play();
        });

        on(fadeInButton, "click", function(evt)
        {
          fx.fadeIn({ node: fadeTarget }).play();
        });

      });           
    </script>       
  </head>
  <body class="claro">
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" id="fadeOutButton">Fade block out</button>
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" id="fadeInButton">Fade block in</button>

    <div id="fadeTarget" style="background: red; height: 256px">
      A red block
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

My goal is to have Dojo style the buttons. As far as I can see, this is done by the parser. The problem with this is that the parser will change the id of the button elements and therefore the events will not be triggered. If I remove `dojo/parser` from `require` or change `parseOnLoad` to 0, the buttons work, but they are not style. With the code above, buttons are styled but do not work. Is it possible to have both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out -- I have to use `registry.byId` instead of `dom.byId`

Comment: registry.byId returns the widget object.  dom.byId returns the DOM object.  So you need to be careful when using the object returned by registry.byId.  If you need the DOM node that is rendering the widget, you need to access the "domNode" property of the widget object.